Show form errors using Spring Boot
I want to do the validation of a form using Spring Boot.
For the same field I want to verify first if it is null and show user the error message and if it's not I want to verify if it has at least 2 and no more than 50 characters. My problem is that, if I don't fill up that field it show both messages, instead of show just the first one (null message). How can I fix it?
@Controller
public class BookController{
(...)
    @RequestMapping(value="add-book", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addNewBook(ModelMap model, @Valid Book book, BindingResult result) { 
        
        if(result.hasErrors())
            return "addUpdateBook";
        
        bookService.addBook(book);
        return "redirect:list-books";
    }
(...)
}

addUpdateBook.jsp
(...)
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="book">
    <fieldset class="mb-3">
        <form:label path="name">Name: </form:label>
        <form:input type="text" path="name"/><br>
        <form:errors path="name" cssClass="text-warning"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

Book.java
public class Book{
(...)
    @NotBlank(message = "Name can not be null.")
    @Size(min=2, max=50, message = "Name must be between {min} and {max} characters long.")
    private String name;

(...)



Spring by defacto uses the hibernate validator to perform field validation.  The Hibernate Validator has a fail fast mode, which will return from the current validation as soon as the first constraint violation occur.  Unfortunately the property is not exposed at the session factory level.  Within your Spring @Configuration you should be able to set the property on the ValidatorFactory:
@Configuration
public class ValidationConfig {

...

  @Bean
  public Validator validator() {
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
            .configure()
            .failFast(true)
            .buildValidatorFactory();
    return validatorFactory.getValidator();
  }

...

}

Just keep in mind that is a global property so now all validations in your application will behave in the same way with fail fast ON.

After adding this, when I don't fill in the field, no error appears

Please let me know what version of Spring Boot you are using.

Version 3.3.1 and Java 17

Ok.  I have edited my answer to appropriately apply for Spring Boot 3.3.x and Spring 6.1.x.  Hopefully this will now work for you.  Good Luck.

All the imports I have to do are from jakarta.validation, right? No change verified

Yes.  Here is the section from the Validator documentation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-provider-specific-settings .  I'm not sure why this isn't working for you.

Ok. I'll investigate better. Thank you
